# Testing scope variables:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I have a scope variable which is bound to service method which returns true or false:

```
vm.checkGuest= myService.getValue();
```

Below are two it conditions where i am checking for false/true.

```
it('should return falsey value for checkGuest variable', function() {  
   var mySpy = sinon.spy(myService, 'setValue');          
   myService.setValue(false);
   expect(myService.setValue.calledOnce).to.equal(false);
   expect(mySpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
   expect(vm.checkGuest).to.equal(false);
});
```

The first one passes, the second one fails.

```
it('should return truthy value for checkGuest variable', function() {  
   var mySpy = sinon.spy(myService, 'setValue');          
   myService.setValue(true);
   expect(myService.setValue.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
   expect(mySpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
   expect(vm.checkGuest).to.equal(true);
});
```

The problem is `myService.getValue()` always returns me false, even though in my second test-case i am setting it as true.

My Service:

```
var appData = {}; 
appData.isGuest = true;

this.setValue = function(flag){
    appData.isGuest = flag;
};

this.getValue = function(){
    return appData.isGuest;
};

appData = this;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be spying on `sinon.spy(myService, 'getValue');` instead of myService.setValue?

Comment: Can you post the code for your service?

Comment: @user2085143: Have updated my service...